# how to fetch data from json action into view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult searchByName(string name)
{
    dbCRMEntities dbx = new dbCRMEntities();
    var test = name;             
    var names = dbx.CONTACTS.Where(chk => name == chk.NAME);
    return this.Json(names, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

This method is returning the data in this format:

```
[
    {
        "CONTACT_ID": 37,
        "NAME": "umair",
        "JOB_TITLE": "internee",
        "COMPANY": "fastservices",
        "PHONE": "244",
        "EMAIL": "umairliaquat@gmail.com",
        "WEB": "alskdjg",
        "ADDRESS": "lahore",
        "STATUS": "Inactive",
        "TAGS": "sdf",
        "LEAD_SOURCE": "partner",
        "BACKGROUND": "skldjga",
        "OWNER": "a",
        "BIRTHDAY": "2014-12-18",
        "EntityState": 2,
        "EntityKey": {
            "EntitySetName": "CONTACTS",
            "EntityContainerName": "dbCRMEntities",
            "EntityKeyValues": [
                {
                    "Key": "CONTACT_ID",
                    "Value": 37
                }
            ],
            "IsTemporary": false
        }
    }
]
```

and my jquery method is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        var name = $("#search").val();
        //name = "ali";
        alert(name);

        $.post("/Status/searchByName", { name: name }, function (data) {
            document.write(data);
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            });
        }, "text");
    });
});
```

I want to obtain data in tabular form in the view. Please guide me

Comment: You just need to create `td` in your loop, appending the value of the property in to it - that hard part is already done.

Comment: Do you already have a table with a blank row that you can clone? Other wise you need to generate the html for the table.

Comment: I had created the table in html,but unable to get the object properties. How can I extract data or attributes from function(data)?

Comment: or use jsrender: http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrplaying

Comment: don't use `document.write` it will wipe out the whole page when used after onload has occured. Log to console instead using `console.log(data)`

Comment: `$.each(data, function (key, value) { console.log(value.CONTACT_ID); });` returns `37` And it should be `$.getJSON(...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke agree that `GET` probably more appropriate but can't `post` with `getJSON`. Throwing that in for clarity

Comment: @charlietfl, OP does not appear to be doing a POST (modifying data), just a GET based on a search parameter (and the return value is even marked `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i do next to no asp / .NET, was just going by `$.post` so if it is interchangeable at server makes sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change `dataType` of `$.post` to `'json'`. Then jQuery will return an array of objects as your `data` argument.

Now within your `each` the first argument will be `index` and the second will be the individual objects

```
$.post("/Status/searchByName", { name: name }, function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (index, item) {               
               var rowData =[];
                rowData.push(item.CONTACT_ID);
                rowData.push(item.COMPANY);
                rowData.push(item.EntityKey.EntitySetName);
                 /* ETC */

                var row ='<tr><td>' + rowData.join('</td><td>') +'</td></tr>';
                $('table').append(row);

        });
    }, "json");
});
```

You could also loop over each of the properties in each object using `$.each` and if it is a primitive value push it into the html

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) { 
     var rowData =[];
    $.each(item, function( key, value){
       if(typeof value !=='object'){
          rowData.push(value);
        }else if( key === 'EntityKey'){
           /* parse to data array*/
        }  
    });
    /* append to table as above */
});
```